# How to display image from JSON URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am having a problem displaying images from a JSON URL. I want to concatenate two strings to display images from the JSON URL, but I got an error in the console and I am not able to display the images.

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "requestType": "bannerImages",
    "basePath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/",
    "bannerPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/",
    "response": {
        "data": [{
            "banner_id": "40",
            "banner_name": "14613036182de40e0d504f583cda7465979f958a98.jpg",
            "banner_link": "",
            "banner_blocked": "0",
            "banner_created": "admin",
            "created_on": "1461303618"
        }, {
            "banner_id": "39",
            "banner_name": "1461303615f99687dd719c4e8bc6a39e946c3d9ef7.jpg",
            "banner_link": "",
            "banner_blocked": "0",
            "banner_created": "admin",
            "created_on": "1461303615"
        }, {
            "banner_id": "38",
            "banner_name": "14613036094efdd2f969559e8b1c92e99f32ded48e.jpg",
            "banner_link": "",
            "banner_blocked": "0",
            "banner_created": "admin",
            "created_on": "1461303609"
        }]
    },
    "request": {
        "postData": [],
        "getData": {
            "type": "bannerImages",
            "result": "json"
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
 NSArray * arr1 = [json objectForKey: @ "bannerPath"];
    NSLog(@ "%@", arr1);
        NSMutableArray * arr2 = [json objectForKey: @ "basePath"];
        NSLog(@ "%@", arr2);
        [statusarray addObject: outstatus];
        [ban_path_arr addObject: arr1];
        [ban_base_arr addObject: arr2];
        [bannerPath_NameArr addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%@%@", arr1,   banname]];
        NSLog(@ "%@", bannerPath_NameArr);
```

Console Error

> 2016 - 05 - 02 10: 13: 31.173 pageview[949: 22534](
>           "http://192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/cdn-images/banner/(\n
>         \"14613036182de40e0d504f583cda7465979f958a98.jpg\",\n
>         \"1461303615f99687dd719c4e8bc6a39e946c3d9ef7.jpg\",\n
>         \"14613036094efdd2f969559e8b1c92e99f32ded48e.jpg\"\n)"
>         )

I got an error like this \n also display unnecessary. I don't know why it is display in URL images.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thank u pang for  edited my content

Comment: You haven't shared `banname` assignment, but it looks like it is the whole array of `banner_name` values (e.g. `valueForKey:@"banner_name"` rather than looping through the values in `data`). But until you show us how you created `banname`, we can't help.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *banname = @"14613036182de40e0d504f583cda7465979f958a98.jpg";
NSString *strImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",banname];

strImageUrl = [strImageUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

[cell.imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageUrl]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Nsarray class for concatenate two strings, use 'stringWithFormat', In your json get both string values and merge that with the Nsstring

Check Code below

```
NSString *banname = @"14613036182de40e0d504f583cda7465979f958a98.jpg";
NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[json objectForKey:@"basePath"],banname];
```

Comment: if i used like this banner name only showed in console,it doesn't display banner path

Comment: surely it will work, First you get both image path in Nsstring from json, and then concatenate

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * str1 = [json objectForKey: @ "bannerPath"];
NSString * str2 = [json objectForKey: @ "basePath"];
str1 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
str2 = [str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];        
NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%@%@", str1,   banname];
imgShow.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImage]]];
```

Comment: if used your code, but my console showed like this only bannername   11:24:33.856 pageview[1388:59423] status 200
2016-05-02 11:24:33.856 pageview[1388:59423] 
(
    "14613036182de40e0d504f583cda7465979f958a98.jpg",

   
 "1461303615f99687dd719c4e8bc6a39e946c3d9ef7.jpg",
   
 "14613036094efdd2f969559e8b1c92e99f32ded48e.jpg"
)

Comment: Please try to do using break point so we will exactly  identify issue